# How to set/get value from ace editor in iframe?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, iframe, ace-editor

I have ace editor with custom mode hosted in heroku, now I can render this app in an iframe but I am unable to get/set the value of ace editor which was present in iframe

I tried to access iframe contents using the following jquery

```
$('#myiframe').contents();
```

got an error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at Error (native)
```

I've tried to solve the above error using https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors
but still I'm getting the same error.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

config/application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```